# .NET Core override controller level Authorize attribute for a specific action

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Here is an example controller to explain the case

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Authorize(Policy = "SpecificPolicy")]
    public string MethodA() {}

    public string MethodB() {}
}
```

- MethodA should only be authorized via "SpecificPolicy".
- MethodB should be authorized via the Authorized attribute

The issue I'm having is that if I remove the AllowAnonymous attribute then Authorize on the controller takes precedence which I don't want for MethodA.

When I keep AllowAnonymous for MethodA then Authorize(Policy = "SpecificPolicy") is ignored.

Answer (score 8):

> When I keep AllowAnonymous for MethodA then Authorize(Policy = "SpecificPolicy") is ignored.

`[AllowAnonymous]` bypasses all other authorization attributes. When you have it with other authorize attributes at the same time, all other attributes are **ignored**, even other attributes are the-more-specific method level.

For example:

```c#
[AllowAnonymous]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

`/dashboard` will be open/public.

> The issue I'm having is that if I remove the AllowAnonymous attribute then Authorize on the controller takes precedence which I don't want for MethodA.

When you have multiple authorize attributes, all of them need to be satisfied before you can make the call to the method. In your case, both `[Authorize]` and `[Authorize(Policy = "SpecificPolicy")]` must pass before access is granted.

If you don't want `[Authorize]` to take the precedence, you can only apply it to method B:

```c#
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "SpecificPolicy")]
    public string MethodA() {}

    [Authorize]
    public string MethodB() {}
}
```

> I want to avoid putting specific [Authorize] attributes on actions since that Controller has lots of actions but a single action that has it's own authorize rule.

Then this might be good time for you to separate MethodA into **Areas**.

For example:

You still have `[Authorize]` on your `AccountController`, but just take out the MethodA:

```c#
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    public string MethodB() {}
}
```

Then you create an Area for MethodA:

```c#
[Area("specific")]
[Authorize(Policy = "SpecificPolicy")]
public abstract class SpecificControllerBase : ControllerBase
{ }

public class AccountController : SpecificationControllerBase
{
    public string MethodA() {}
}
```

Lastly you need to register the area route in your `Startup.cs`:

```c#
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    ...

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areaRoute",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=dashboard}/{action=index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Your response makes sense, I want to avoid putting specific [Authorize] attributes on actions since that Controller has lots of actions but a single action that has it's own authorize rule. So I think a better approach if it can't be done in one controller is to move that single method to its own controller.

Comment: @Exocomp: I understand. When your case happens, I just talk to myself: "hmm maybe I should create an area for that method, under a controller with the same name". With the help of areas, you can put specific authorization policies there. Its URL looks more formal to me too. i.e., `/dashboard` vs `/admin/dashboard` vs `/vendor/dashboard`.

Comment: I didn’t think of using areas. Can you please elaborate with an example in your answer.

Comment: @Exocomp: See my updates. Again there are many ways to achieve your goal. Using an area is just my thought. Others might have better solutions. And I just made things up in the example. Also you can apply the policy attribute either on the abstract base class or on the controller. But I think doing it on the base class makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to implement your own `Authorize Attribute` with checking the Policy.

Follow Steps below:

- `AllowAnonymousWithPolicyFilter`

  ```
  public class AllowAnonymousWithPolicyFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
  {
  private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorization;
  public string Policy { get; private set; }

  public AllowAnonymousWithPolicyFilter(string policy, IAuthorizationService authorization)
  {
      Policy = policy;
      _authorization = authorization;
  }

  public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
  {
      var authorized = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, Policy);
      if (!authorized.Succeeded)
      {
          context.Result = new ForbidResult();
          return;
      }
  }
  }
  ```
- AllowAnonymousWithPolicyAttribute

  ```
  public class AllowAnonymousWithPolicyAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute, IAllowAnonymous
  {
  public AllowAnonymousWithPolicyAttribute(string Policy) : base(typeof(AllowAnonymousWithPolicyFilter))
  {
      Arguments = new object[] { Policy };
  }
  }
  ```
- Use

  ```
  [Authorize]
   public class HomeController : Controller
  {
  [AllowAnonymousWithPolicy("MyPolicy")]
  public IActionResult About()
  {
      ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

      return View();
  }
  ```

Comment: This has been very helpful however there is one minor issue with this example. If your policy handlers need the AuthorizationFilterContext you need to pass it to AuthorizeAsync method. This method has a lot of overrides and the one used here defaults the context to null.

Comment: You can put Authorize attribute and AllowAnonymous attribute on the same controller/action. If the user is authenticated, the User property of the controller will be set as the authenticated user. If there is no authentication, then the AllowAnonymous attribute still allows the action to run, but with the User property not being set and show as not authenticated. This only works though if you use Authorization Policies, and not just authorization schemes.