# ASP.NET Core 3.1 having Basic and JWT authorization and custom Policy

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, basic-authentication

I need to have JWT and Basic authorization at the same time in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 app.

Here is my startup config:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
    ...
});
    
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("BasicAuth", policyBuilder =>
     {
         policyBuilder.Requirements.Add(new BasicAuthenticationRequirement());
     });
    
  options.AddPolicy("Customer", policyBuilder =>
      {
         policyBuilder.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme);
         policyBuilder.RequireRole("Customer");
      });
});
```

Also :

```
 services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, BasicAuthenticationHandler>();
```

I needed to add `BasicAuthenticationHandler`, because I need to access `IHttpContextAccessor` :

```
 public BasicAuthenticationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
 {
 }
```

But the issue here is that, for each request to be authorized, even it has [Authorize(Policy = "Customer")] it will not consider "JwtBearer" and skips the authorize and runs the action.

**Update**

Despite that the action it self has [Authorize] attribute, the controller has [AllowAnonymous] attribute and when I removed it from the controller and let the action has the [Authorize], it worked.

[.NET Core override controller level Authorize attribute for a specific action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729492/net-core-override-controller-level-authorize-attribute-for-a-specific-action)

Comment: actually it must consider the jwt bearer first (in the authentication phase) before verifying your `Customer` policy (in the authorization phase). From what you described, I understand that the user is authenticated OK and has a role of `Customer`. So it's a perfect pass-through to your action. Consider adding more detail to your question (e.g: how you configure the authentication with jwt, what is the controller action that you expect to be protected? and more contextual info about the user sending the request ...)

Comment: If you add `[authorize]` to the controller and action respectively. They are intersection. Before authorization, asp.net core must be through authentication, and JwtBearer will be involved at this time.